# Entity Framework Many-to-Many Madness

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4.1

[image: Database Diagram]

Ok, don't shoot me for the following db structure.  I inherited this, I did not create it. What I'm trying to do though is to simplify my life.  I'm currently  using EF 4.1 Code First and I know how to do many-to-many mappings through tables with the fluent api, but I'm completely lost as to how to handle this structure.  Bascially I'd like to be able to map from the IDB_interface table to the IDB_AddressIPv4 table by using a single navigation property?  However, I'm guessing this isn't possible?  Any constructive thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Starting over isn't an option or changing the db structure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not as designed, I don't think so.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but could you add a layer of views to the database which expose a more sane relational model for EF to work with?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible with EF as I faced a similar situation. One solution is to create an extension class with a method to retrieve the `IDB_AddressIPv4` for the specified `IDB_Interface` by going through the mapping tables. This will at least simplify your calls and not repeat code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must live with the structure you have. EF code first has no tools to help you. It can only simplify many-to-many relation with single junction table without additional data - that is not your case.

This is a case where it would be really handy to add additional layer on top of EF which would simplify your model to desired entities and your persistence logic will transform it to this horror.

Comment: So can I even use EF in this situation?  I'm having trouble getting the maps to work without any simplification.  I can map a collection of layer3 address to an interface, but for an instance of the layer3 objects,  the InterfaceIPv4 table isn't mapping?